# Calling saveAsync from Outlook add-in returns warning notification for an event

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

My Outlook add-in has a compose scenario for an event (extension point : `AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface`). The add-in loads the `itemId`, makes a REST call to the API to get relevant datas from it and save some calculated datas in the `CustomProperties` field of the item.

The code ends with `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync();`

Nevertheless, trying to close the event throws a pop-up asking if the user wants to save changes or not.

How could that be since the last executed code is a `saveAsync` method on the item ?

Edit : the pop-up occurs only using `outlook.office.com` but doesn't appear on Outlook dekstop.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, Sybic2001. We are aware of the issue and will continue investigating it.

Comment: @Sybic, how to load `itemId` in event compose mode? I have a similar requirement to load itemId in event compose mode. But as per [Office API documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5), itemId is not supported in compose/edit mode?

Comment: @MK446 you have to perform a `saveAsync` on the item : in the callback, you will get the itemId !